# Iterating through 3 loops of different length - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays and i want to make a 3rd array after comparison of the 2 arrays. Code is as follows:

```
foreach($allrsltntcatg as $alltests)
{
  foreach($alltests as $test)
  {
    foreach($allCatgs as $catg)
    {
      if($catg['testcategoryid'] == $test['testcategory_testcategoryid'])
      {
         $catcounts[$catg['testcategoryname']] +=1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It, although returns the right answer, it also generates a PHP error and says undefined index and prints all errors and also the right answer.

I just want to avoid the array out of bound error. Kindly help me

Comment: show your array

Comment: "I have **three two** arrays".

Comment: When the array try to add some arithmetic operation of undefined index such as `$catg['testcategoryname']` in the `$catcounts` array then the warning generates. __Before add the number you have to check the index is present or not, and of not then just assign value otherwise add into it.__

Comment: Actually there are two arrays.

Comment: just use ISSET to check the value is isset or not

Comment: @FrayneKonok you are right and i just want to avoid that error.

Comment: @JamshaidSabir, Checkout my answer.

Comment: You could just use `@` for error suppression: `@$catcounts[$catg['testcategoryname']] +=1;`

Comment: @moni_dragu, As a programmer you can't use the `@` for hide warning, This is very bad and harmful also.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in if condition correct like below : You have to initialize array first and than you can increment value

```
if($catg['testcategoryid'] == $test['testcategory_testcategoryid'])
{
    if (isset($catcounts[$catg['testcategoryname']]))
         $catcounts[$catg['testcategoryname']] +=1;
    else
         $catcounts[$catg['testcategoryname']] =1;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept this answer as right :-)

Answer (score 0):

When the array try to add some arithmetic operation of undefined index such as `$catg['testcategoryname']` in the `$catcounts` array then the warning generates. Before add the number you have to check the index is present or not, and of not then just assign value otherwise add into it.

So do it in this way just if condition-

```
if(....){
    if(array_key_exists($catg['testcategoryname'], $catcounts))
        $catcounts[$catg['testcategoryname']] +=1; // Add into it
    else
        $catcounts[$catg['testcategoryname']] = 1; // Assign only

}
```

More about array key exists--[See more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Answer (score 0):

`$catg['testcategoryname']` should represent an index in `$catcounts` array.